# How to use if else in text property to display either one value or another?

Tags: sapui5

Having two distinct values such as `QtValidF` and `DocDate`, I want to be able to **display `DocDate` only if `QtValidF` comes `null`**. How could I condition this?

```xml
<Text text="{
  path: 'QtValidF',
  formatter:'.formatoFecha'
}"/>
```

I'm trying this but doesn't work.

```xml
<Text text="{= ${QtValidF} != 'null' ? {
  path: 'DocDate',
  formatter: '.formatoFecha'
} : {
  path: 'QtValidF',
  formatter: '.formatoFecha'
}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Expression Binding

In general, you can make use of [expression binding](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) for a **short and simple** conditional expression.

```xml
<MyControl anyProperty="{= ${myPrimary} || ${mySecondary}}" />
```

Just like in JS, when the first operand results in one of the [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the second one is taken into account.

### Formatter

In case a [formatter is preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768645/how-to-use-if-else-in-text-property-to-display-either-one-value-or-another#comment88618919_50768645), the *composite binding* syntax can be used:

```xml
<MyControl anyProperty="{
  parts: [
    'myPrimary',
    'mySecondary'
  ],
  formatter: '.getThatValue'
}" />
```

Then in the controller:

```js
getThatValue: function(primaryValue, secondaryValue) {
  return primaryValue || secondaryValue;
},
```

For more information, please take a look at the topics [Binding Syntax](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e2e6f4127fe4450ab3cf1339c42ee832) and [Composite Binding](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [inline binding expression](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0):

```
value='{= ${/QValidF} !== null ? ${/QValidF} : ${/DocDate} }'
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Bernard LeTourneur - UI5 Single Page</title>
        <script
         src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
            id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
            data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
            data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax='complex'
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion='edge'
            data-sap-ui-preload='async'>    
        </script>
        <script id='myXmlView' type='ui5/xmlview'>
            <mvc:View
                controllerName='MyController'
                xmlns='sap.m'
                xmlns:core='sap.ui.core'
                xmlns:mvc='sap.ui.core.mvc'>
                <Input id='inputStatus' enabled='false' value='{= ${/QValidF} !== null ? ${/QValidF} : ${/DocDate} }' />
                <Button press="handleDataChange" text='{= ${/QValidF} !== null ? "Set QValidF to Null" : "Set QValidF to something"}' />
            </mvc:View>
        </script>
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                'use strict';

                sap.ui.define([
                    'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
                    'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
                ], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
                    'use strict';

                    return Controller.extend('MyController', {

                        onInit : function () {                     
                            var that = this;
                            var data = {QValidF: "something", DocDate: "2018/06/08"};
                            var oModel = new JSONModel(data);
                            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
                        },
                        handleDataChange: function(){
                            var isNull = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/QValidF");
                            console.log(isNull);
                            if (isNull=="something"){
                                this.getView().getModel().setProperty("/", {QValidF: null, DocDate: "2018/06/08"});
                            }
                            else{
                                this.getView().getModel().setProperty("/", {QValidF: "something", DocDate: "2018/06/08"});
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery('#myXmlView').html()
                }).placeAt('content');

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class='sapUiBody'>
        <div id='content'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```